# nginxにて存在しないURLへのアクセスで大量の404が発生。あるURLの404の閾値を超えたらnginx側でリクエストを返す方法は？

Tags: linux, nginx

URLが存在しないページへ大量のアクセスがある場合、404を返していますが、アプリケーションへのリソースがかかるため、ある一定の閾値が超えたら、nginx側で（もしくはアプリケーションが動く手前で）返してしまいたいと思っています。

どのような方法を取るのがよいまたは一般的なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit_req_zone`と言うモジュールがあります。例えば下記だと毎秒5リクエストに制限されます。

```
limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=one:10m   rate=5r/s;
```

詳しくは公式ドキュメントを参照して下さい。 http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回は短時間の集中アクセスに限らず、例えば毎秒1リクエストずつ、あるURLで404を発生され続けるような場合の対処も含めて検討しています

Comment: 複雑な場合はnginxでluaを使って書くか、アプリ側で対処する必要があると思います。